# Добавить класс и удалить при повторном клике

Tags: jquery

```
<div class="checkbox_block_row">
    <div class="checkbox">
     11
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
       22
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
       33
    </div>
</div>
```

Нужно, чтобы при клике на `checkbox` добавлялся класс `checkbox_active`,  при этом, если я кликну следующий `checkbox` нужно чтобы с предыдущего не удалился класс, а при повторном клике на элемент с него удалился класс `checkbox_active`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно через **делегирование** и скрипт будет **намного быстрее** работать:

```js
$( ".checkbox_block_row" ).on( "click", ".checkbox" , function() {
  $( this ).toggleClass( "checkbox_active" );
});
```

```css
.checkbox {
    color: red;
    user-select: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.checkbox_active {
    color: green !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="checkbox_block_row">
        <div class="checkbox">
           11
       </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
           22
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
           33
        </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: As of jQuery 3.0, .delegate() has been deprecated. It was superseded by the .on() method since jQuery 1.7, so its use was already discouraged.

Comment: Ок, заменил на on :)

Comment: But I do this first:(

Comment: откатил изменения

Comment: Да не, я же пошутил. Я не против, просто делегирование быстрее и главное помнить это.

Comment: :) на самом деле, в данном конкретном случае "намного быстрее" скрипт работать не будет, так что делегированием тут можно пренебречь. А вот если чекбоксы добавляются динамически после формирования DOM, то без delegate не обойтись.

Answer (score 3):

```js
$('.checkbox_block_row .checkbox').on('click', function(event){
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

```css
.active {
color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="checkbox_block_row">
    <div class="checkbox">
     11
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
       22
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
       33
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Только если нажать на 11, а потом на 22 то с 11 уйдет класс, а нужно что-бы остался пока я не нажму 11 что-бы удалить его с помощью клика

Comment: обновил пример, убрал часть       $('.active').not($(this)).removeClass('active');

Comment: Не совсем идеальный вариант :)