# Добавить/удалить класс

Tags: jquery

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    1
    <div>
      ghi
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    2
    <div>
      def
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    3
    <div>
      abc
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Помогите пожалуйста решить задачу. 
1. При клике на `<li>` нужно добавить класс этому `<li>`, а так же вложенному `<div>`, при повторном клике на этот же `<li>`добавленные классы должны удалиться.
2. При добавленном классе если кликнуть на другой `<li>` классы должны удалиться и добавиться тому `<li>` и вложенному `<div>` на который кликнули.
Классы для `<li>`и`<div>` разные.

Comment: С чем именно нужна помощь? Что у вас не получилось?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Добавить класс и удалить при повторном клике](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/825614/%d0%94%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81-%d0%b8-%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$('li').click(function() {
    let hasFoo = $(this).hasClass('foo');
    let hasBaz = $(this).find('div').hasClass('baz');
    
    if (!hasFoo && !hasBaz) {
        $('li').removeClass('foo');
        $('li').find('div').removeClass('baz'); 
    }
    
    $(this).toggleClass('foo');
    $(this).find('div').toggleClass('baz'); 
});
```

```css
.foo {
  font-size: 18px;
}

.baz {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    1
    <div>
      ghi
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    2
    <div>
      def
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    3
    <div>
      abc
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Нужно чтоб только один элемент списка имел класс, а у вас можно всем класс добавить(

Comment: @GreyRat исправил

Comment: Огромное, спасибо! Вы мне очень помогли!